# colorize area of point cloud on a 2D image

Tags: c++, opencv, pointcloud

I am projecting a 3D Point Cloud on a 2D image incoming as ROS 2 messages. Now, I want to fill the gaps between pixels from the point cloud, so that I can see an area, instead of single pixels and publish the overlay (point cloud + camera) image. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688703/algorithm-for-overlaying-point-cloud-on-image) a similar question, but unfortunately it hasn't been answered.

What I am trying to achieve is:

before
[image]

after
[image]

I tried at first some voronoi diagram, but I haven't succeeded. My Node is written in C++ using OpenCV for image processing.

Does anyone has an idea, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve better results with [cv::dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html).

As far as I tested, I haven't lost any perfomance and it is really easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good approach could be:

- get the convex hull of each point set with [`convexHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html)
- fill the polygons with [`drawContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Even easier, if you know that your region are always going to be axis aligned rectangles as in the example image:

- get the min and max of both X and Y coordinates in each point set
- draw rectangles on the image with [`rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html)

For both `rectangle` and `drawContours` you can specify a negative `thickness` value to have the shape filled in the specified color.

A minor comment if you have similar doubts in the future: try to post a minimal working example, and possibly make it ROS-independent (e.g. save the projected points in JSON and the image as JPG) to ask for advice also on StackOverflow (or any other forum).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I achieved better results using the [cv::dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) function. Thank you for your input anyway.